# Patch corruption or loss after rebase

Tags: mercurial, patch, tortoisehg

I just lost all of the changes in a Mercurial patch (fortunately, I had a backup), and I would like to figure out what went wrong.

## The Setup

I had a pair of patches, call them patch1.diff and patch2.diff. They were both based on revision 123, but affected completely different files, with no overlap. So, my repository looked something like this in TortoiseHg (where `p` is a patch and `r` is a regular revision):

```
Graph  Rev   Branch   Tags          Message
  p    125   develop  patch2.diff   Change to existing file baz.php

  p    124   develop  patch1.diff   Add new files foo.php and bar.php

  r    123   develop                Last committed changeset
  |
  r    122   develop                Old changes
  ...
```

## What I Did

I wanted to switch the order of the patches, because my work on patch2.diff was complete and I wanted to commit those changes. So I tried rebasing that patch onto revision 123. That didn't work, and I ended up with something like this:

```
Graph  Rev   Branch   Tags          Message
    r                               Working directory - not a head revision!

    r  126   develop                Change to existing file baz.php
    |
  p |  125   develop  patch2.diff   Change to existing file baz.php
    |
  p |  124   develop  patch1.diff   Add new files foo.php and bar.php
    |
  r-+  123   develop                Last committed changeset
  |
  r    122   develop                Old changes
  ...
```

That was clearly wrong. I now had a revision 126 with the same changes as those in patch2.diff, but I also still had a patch2.diff, which wasn't rebased as I expected. On top of that, I was getting the "not a head revision" message, even though there weren't actually any changes in my working directory.

So I stripped revision 126. At that point, things went completely off the rails, leaving me with this:

```
Graph  Rev   Branch   Tags          Message
  p    125   develop  patch2.diff   Change to existing file baz.php

  p    124   develop  patch1.diff

  r    123   develop                Last committed changeset
  |
  r    122   develop                Old changes
  ...
```

patch1.diff still appeared in TortoiseHg, but the changes and commit message were gone. I tried `hg qpush --all`, and got these messages:

```
applying patch1.diff
unable to read patch1.diff
```

I couldn't even find patch1.diff on my file system anymore. Ultimately, I had to run `hg qdelete --keep patch1.diff` and then restore my lost changes from offsite backups.

I ended up where I wanted to be, but nearly lost hours of work on a new feature. I was able to recover only because I had an offsite backup of the new files. That was terrifying.

## The Question

What in the world happened? Why did I lose patch1.diff? I could understand if I lost the changes in patch2.diff given the way I used `hg strip`, but I have no idea why patch1.diff got nuked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stumbled over the issues why mq might very soon not be recommended anymore. It wants to retain control over csets it controls and it looses that, when you modify history under mq control. Thus mq does not work well with rebase, strip, histedit...

The better way is to simply stop using mq at all. Make your default phase for new commits secret (or draft). Commit your patches as normal changesets - then mq cannot interfer with proper working of rebase and what you did try to do would simply have worked.
hg rebase -s125 -d123
hg rebase -s124 -d126
(given the state of your repo as in the first quote, just asusming r124, r125 are normal csets, not under mq control)

And if you're a little daring, you take a look at the evolve extension which is very useful for people who maintain patch queues with respect to upstream repos or juggle draft changesets with collaborators.
See http://www.logilab.org/blogentry/88203 for an introduction to mercurial phases